# converting getrusage from linux to windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I'm converting a linux C++ code to Windows and I'm struggling with a replacement for this `getrusage` method.

```
1.    timeval CPUStopwatch::now_timeval() const {
2.        rusage ru;
3.        getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &ru);
4.        return ru.ru_utime;
5.    }
```

How can I parse this line (3) to a working windows line? I've implemented both `rusage` and `timeval` classes, so they won't be a problem.

Comment: They are different operating systems and I don't think Windows has a direct translation for all the fields in the linux `rusage` struct.

Comment: I guess it doesn't have, that's why I'm asking. I'm searching for any clue on how to get this working the way it does in linux. The best I could find was a [linux implementation](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/mach/hurd/getrusage.c.html).

Comment: If the OS doesn't have something similar, I don't think you can get it working the way it does in linux. Similarly: Windows has a lot of OS information that you can query for that is not available in linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL source code you can find :

```
 /*
 * This code works on:
 *      solaris_i386
 *      solaris_sparc
 *      hpux 9.*
 *      win32
 * which currently is all the supported platforms that don't have a
 * native version of getrusage().  So, if configure decides to compile
 * this file at all, we just use this version unconditionally.
 */

int
getrusage(int who, struct rusage *rusage)
{
#ifdef WIN32
    FILETIME    starttime;
    FILETIME    exittime;
    FILETIME    kerneltime;
    FILETIME    usertime;
    ULARGE_INTEGER li;

    if (who != RUSAGE_SELF)
    {
        /* Only RUSAGE_SELF is supported in this implementation for now */
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    if (rusage == (struct rusage *) NULL)
    {
        errno = EFAULT;
        return -1;
    }
    memset(rusage, 0, sizeof(struct rusage));
    if (GetProcessTimes(GetCurrentProcess(),
                        &starttime, &exittime, &kerneltime, &usertime) == 0)
    {
        _dosmaperr(GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    /* Convert FILETIMEs (0.1 us) to struct timeval */
    memcpy(&li, &kerneltime, sizeof(FILETIME));
    li.QuadPart /= 10L;         /* Convert to microseconds */
    rusage->ru_stime.tv_sec = li.QuadPart / 1000000L;
    rusage->ru_stime.tv_usec = li.QuadPart % 1000000L;

    memcpy(&li, &usertime, sizeof(FILETIME));
    li.QuadPart /= 10L;         /* Convert to microseconds */
    rusage->ru_utime.tv_sec = li.QuadPart / 1000000L;
    rusage->ru_utime.tv_usec = li.QuadPart % 1000000L;
#else                           /* all but WIN32 */
```

From https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/7559d8ebfa11d98728e816f6b655582ce41150f3/src/port/getrusage.c